# what is this "for-loop" doing?

Tags: java, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [foreach loop a java creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518111/foreach-loop-a-java-creation)

I am learning a Java program. But something , I don't understand. It is following:

```
for(Some obj : vc) {
  System.out.println(obj.getResult());
```

I tried to search "for-loop" in my book and google. They just had some basic method.

What means about "for(Some obj : vc)"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), introduced in Java 1.5.

You can read it as "For each `Some` in `vc`".

It's effectively the same as using an iterator like so:

```
for(Iterator<Some> i = vc.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
  Some obj = i.next();
  System.out.println(obj.getResult());
}
```

Only with less bloat.

Also, note that this syntax isn't limited to things that are `Iterable`.  This would also work if `vc` were an array of `Some` (i.e. `Some[]`).

Comment: Thanks for Tim. From your translation, I can get the meaning about this now. Thanks again!